# Graph the function and apply the appropriate transformations $y = (1)/( x + 4)$

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

> Graph the function and apply the appropriate transformations $y =  1/( x + 4)  $

I know this much. My denominator can not be zero, thus $x+4 \neq 0$ which gives me $x > -4 $; in interval notation, $(-\infty,-4)\cup(-4,\infty)$.

Now if I was to sketch the graph (not exactly) the end behavior would be:

- as $x$ approaches $-\infty $, $y$ approaches $-\infty $
- when x approaches $\infty,$ $y$ approaches $\infty $

Am I correct?

Comment: No they both approach to zero.

Comment: as $x\to \infty$ then $y\to 0$ and similarly for $-\infty$, first plot the graph of $y=\frac{1}{x}$ then try to plot your graph by shifting the axes

Comment: Why are the approaching 0? are they not approaching -4 and the left headed to -00 on the y axis while the right side is headed to +00 on the y axis?

Answer (score 0):

The interval you got is correct, but not because $x + 4 > 0$ but because $x + 4 \neq 0$

The second part of the exercise is wrong:
As $x$ approaches to $+\infty $   you get y = $\frac{1}{smth\ BIG}$ which tends to $0^+$

In the same way, as $x$ approaches to $-\infty $   you get y = $\frac{1}{smth\ (-1)BIG}$ which tends to $0^-$

Comment: 1/8 = 0.125, that is much smaller.